# How can I solve for the Triangle formed by the intersection of two circles?

Tags: trigonometry

For two circles with center points on an $X$ axis $(x_1, 0); (x_2,0)$, and for which the center of the second circle lies on the circumference of the first circle at $(x_2, 0)$; there is a triangle that can be drawn with corners originating at 1) the intersection of the first circle with the $X$ axis; 2) the center of the second circle $(x_2,0)$; and 3) the intersection point of the two circles.  (So, corners at (0,0); (10,0); and one of the intersection points of the two circles).

I am trying to find a way to get the angles of this triangle.

So, for example, for two circles - first one with radius $5$ centered at $(5,0)$, and the second circle with radius $1$ centered at $(10,0)$, how can I find the values of the triangle formed?

Related: how can I find the value for the triangle formed if we drop a line down at $90$-degrees from the center of the second circle at $(10,0)$ to give a right triangle?

Comment: You are correct.  I think I fixed it now.

Comment: The first circle intersects the $x$-axis in two places. Are both of them corners of the triangle? It that's the case, look up Thales' theorem.

Comment: Thank you Arthur.  Thales' theorem allows me to know the length of one side of the triangle and one angle (90-degrees).  I do not know how to find the final value I need to solve for the triangle (the length of another side, or another angle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given :-

1 :- Equation of The circles  $(x - x_1)^2 + y^2 = r_1^2$ and $(x - x_2)^2 + y^2 = r_2^2$

2:- $x_2 = x_1 \pm r_1$

---

$$(x - x_2)^2 + y^2 = r_2^2$$
$$\Rightarrow  (x - (x_1 + r_1))^2 + y^2 = r_2^2 $$

> $$y^2 = r_1^2 - (x - x_1)^2$$

$$\Rightarrow  (x - (x_1 + r_1))^2 - (x - x_1)^2 + r_1^2 = r_2^2 $$
$$\Rightarrow  (x - (x_1 + r_1) - (x - x_1))(x - (x_1 + r_1) + (x - x_1)) = r_2^2 - r_1^2 $$
$$\Rightarrow  (2x - 2x_1) = { r_1^2 - r_2^2  \over  r_1} + r_1$$
$$\Rightarrow  x = {2r_1^2 - r_2^2  \over  2r_1} + x_1$$
$$\therefore y = \pm\sqrt{r_1^2 - {(2r_1^2 - r_2^2)^2  \over  4r_1^2} } $$

---

the vertices  of the triangle are $(x_1 -  r_1, 0)$, $(x_2 = x_1 + r_1, 0)$ and $\left( {2r_1^2 - r_2^2  \over  2r_1} + x_1, \sqrt{r_1^2 - {(2r_1^2 - r_2^2)^2  \over  4r_1^2} }  \right)$

---

So for your example vertices are $(0, 0)$, $(10, 0)$ and $\left( 9.9, 0.99  \right)$

So angles, $5.7^{\circ}, 84.28^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the upper triangle (in the first quadrant). Name it $\Delta ABC$, so that the vertices are $A(0, 0)$, $B(10, 0)$, and $C(p, q)$, where $p, q > 0$. Notice that since $AB = 10$ is the diameter of the larger circle, we know that $\angle C = 90^\circ$. Since $BC$ is the radius of the smaller circle, we know that $BC = 1$. Using primary trig ratios, we know that $\tan\angle A = 1/10$ so that:
$$
\angle A \approx 5.7^\circ \qquad\text{and}\qquad\angle B = 90^\circ - \angle A \approx 84.3^\circ
$$